# Oracle - Sorting a VARCHAR2 field like a NUMBER - I found a solution, need explanation on it

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have a VARCHAR2 column that I want to sort numerically.  99% (or possibly even 100%) of the time it will contain numbers.  I was looking around and found [this solution](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/sort1.php).  Quoting the source:

> Remember that our goal is to sort the supplier_id field in ascending order (based on its 
>   numeric value). To do this, try using
>   the LPAD function.
>
> For example,
>
> select * from supplier order by
>   lpad(supplier_id, 10);
>
> This SQL pads the front of the
>   supplier_id field with spaces up to 10
>   characters. Now, your results should
>   be sorted numerically in ascending
>   order.

I've played around a little bit with this solution and it seems to be workign (so far), but **how** does it work, can anyone explain?

Comment: Well, technically that sorts the field like an INTEGER, not a number. If you had any decimal numbers in there it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When sorting strings/varchar, the field is always serted from left to right, like you would sort normal words.

That is why you have problems when sorting

```
1
2
3
10
11
20
```

which would be sorted as

```
1
10
11
2
20
3
```

But, now if you pad the values left, you will have something like

```
001
002
003
010
011
020
```

which would sort correctly